# What is the fastest possible slot car

Tags: structural-engineering, motors, electrical, traction

What is the fastest possible slot car one can build? What are the limiting factors?

Obviously, we have to require that the motor is aboard the car and that it's propelled by the wheels (we don't want a particle collider or a rocket), and we want a closed track and go many rounds (we don't want a drag racer).

I guess we would build a large looping, but at which speed will it break from centrifugal force? How much energy can we pump into the car before the track melts? Can we cool the whole race track down to use superconductors? Do we want to evacuate the whole track to avoid sound barrier effects or do we need air for something (cooling? aerodynamic control surfaces on the car?)?

Comment: Will you do this in space to avoid air resistance as that is one of the limiting factors. Check out maxing the Bugatti Veyron.

Comment: Your question looks too broad. Are you're thinking about a normal car or a slot car (like the toy) there will be differences. Ideally you need to estipulate the constraints in the system to work about the limiting factors. For example: Whats the size/dimensions you're thinking in the car and the track?, where you want the fuel/eletricity to be stored (inside the car? outside?). There's lots of things to consider, you need some sketch about the limits to work the real (physical) limits of the system.

Comment: @Leafk I think about a slot car (electrical motor, powered track), size doesn't really matter (but I doubt that a larger car will always be faster than a small one), the power comes from the track (the car has to have some kind of collector)

Comment: I think John Stapp still has the [record](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=omtISQp5bKg) at around 600 mph. <edit> Oops, you didn't want a rocket.

Comment: Are there turns in your track. That probably would limit speed more than anything else.

Comment: @EricShain the track can be designed as needed to get the car as fast as possible, as long as it's closed so you can go multiple rounds.